# error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '802.0.41.0_0' Reader: '703.0.31_0')

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I know this has been asked and answered a lot of time but here is what my issue is. I am trying to integrate Google Sign In into my app, went through their steps and created a demo app and everything works fine. However I have an application which uses Facebook sign in and whenever I try to integrate Google Sign In into that app I get this error.
[image]
 I am using XCode 7.3.1 (please don't bash me). Following are the questions bugging me from a couple of days.
1 - If this is an issue with XCode being oudated w.r.t the library why does the demo app I created work ? (Since all the answers on SO ask to update the XCode.)

2 - The app in which I want to integrate Google Sign In works fine with FBSDK, so why does XCode give that error when I integrate Google Sign In ?

3 - If both libraries work perfectly in two different projects why is there an issue when I try to integrate them in a single project ?

For the Google Sign In I tried with pods as well as Manual set-up, but the error still occurs. The FBSDK was not installed using pods.

Comment: I don't know the libraries you're trying to use but do you have an option to build everything from source?

Comment: I am just using FBSDK and trying to integrate Google Sign In, but that error won't let me do it. Also what do you mean by 'build everything from source' ? Thank you.